# Does anyone know why certain TCP inner workings are called FLAGS?

Tags: ip, tcp

What's the reason for calling certain TCP inner workings flags?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic due to historical trivia.

Answer (score 3):

Flags in software are yes/no options that can be turned off and on.